# Xamarin.Forms WCF endpoint not listening

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

We made a Xamarin form application and are trying to connect to a external WCF host that already exist, we can access it in our browser but not with our application. We made a service reference in our application to the webhost.
This is the error that we get:
[error we get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2txID.png)

This is our code of our mainpage:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xxx.xxxWCF;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace xxx
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://www.xxxx.xxx.be/wcf/xxxservice.svc");
        private xxxClient _client;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeHelloWorldServiceClient();

        }


        private void InitializeHelloWorldServiceClient()
        {

            //    BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();

            _client = new xxxClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://www.labyt.xxx.be/wcf/xxxservice.svc"));

            _client.InloggenVoorAndroidCompleted += InloggenVoorAndroidToCompleted;



        }
//this is a click event from a button we created on the mainpage
        private void InloggenVoorAndroid(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            _client.InloggenVoorAndroidAsync("username", "password");


        }
        private void InloggenVoorAndroidToCompleted(object sender, InloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs inloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs)
        {


            string msg = null;

            if (inloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
            {
                msg = inloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
            }
            else if (inloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
            {
                msg = "Request was cancelled.";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = inloggenVoorAndroidCompletedEventArgs.Result.username;
            }
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => labelNaam.Text = msg);

        }
        private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
            {

                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                Namespace = "xxxService.IService",
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            };

            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            return binding;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you refer to the error in the title of your question. Something like TemporaryKey error ...

Comment: Sorry we just noticed that we added the wrong image, we edited it now to the right one. If you think the title is still not clear, please let us know. It's our first time here